# Page index control

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I am looking for a control to index all my pages. I want to put 20 posts (that i made out of the table control), onto one page..and make it possible for the user to flip through the posts when click a button that is marked as a number. So if he is on page 2, and presses 4..it will direct him to page 4. I am looking for an ajax like control that will generate a bar of numeric buttons that will represent page index..

Is there such an ajax control or way to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

This is most often called a pager.  The asp.net data grid implements that automatically, but if you want to implement your own take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ASPNETPagerControl.aspx).

Comment: damn, it employs stored procedures. it is a nice article..but i want to deploy things programmatically.. is that pager control in the toolbox?

Comment: Just don't utilize the stored procedures. databinding works on most data.

Comment: Where can i find the pager control?